# Autenticação auth laravel

Tags: laravel

Bom dia pessoal, decidi desabilitar usuários, agora gostaria de saber como posso permitir login de usuário somente habilitados, na tabela users adicionei uma coluna chamada disable, se o disable do usuário for false permite o login, se não redireciona para a tela de login, fico no aguardo.

Comment: em que método coloco essa regra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu aconselho você a usar o `softDelete` do Laravel para desabilitar os usuários. Aí você não precisa alterar o método de autenticação. e até para você "desabilitar" os usuários é mais simples.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting